# Where to put images that are called by css file in Django?

Tags: python, html, css, django, templates

I have downloaded a template online that includes a base html file, images and a css file. Now I would like to implement all this in django.

So far I tried like this but with no good results, the page gets rendered without css file or without images, or both... well something is wrong

settings.py:

```
MEDIA_ROOT = rel('resources')
MEDIA_URL = '/resources/'
```

base.html:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="resources/style.css" />
```

I have put my images and the css file in the resources folder and the templates folder and it doesnt work, please help

Answer (score 2):

**EDIT:**

I was slightly off there... STATIC_ROOT refers to the directory where Django will collect all static files. STATICFILES_DIRS is a list of searchpaths for static files. So like this:

settings.py:

```
# Absolute path to the directory static files should be collected to.
# Don't put anything in this directory yourself; store your static files
# in apps' "static/" subdirectories and in STATICFILES_DIRS.
# Example: "/home/media/media.lawrence.com/static/"
STATIC_ROOT = PROJECT_ROOT + 'static/'

# URL prefix for static files.
# Example: "http://media.lawrence.com/static/"
STATIC_URL =  '/static/'

# Additional locations of static files
STATICFILES_DIRS = (
    # Put strings here, like "/home/html/static" or "C:/www/django/static".
    # Always use forward slashes, even on Windows.
    # Don't forget to use absolute paths, not relative paths.
    "C:/www/django/static",
)

# List of finder classes that know how to find static files in
# various locations.
STATICFILES_FINDERS = (
    'django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.FileSystemFinder',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.AppDirectoriesFinder',
)
```

and add the url to urls.py:

```
urlpatterns += staticfiles_urlpatterns()
```

---

**ORIGINAL ANSWER:**

This can be quite confusing.
The MEDIA_ROOT directory is for files uploaded via a file-upload form. For physical files that are directly accessible by client request (e.g style sheets, scripts and images) you have to use the STATIC_ROOT and STATIC_URL. STATIC_ROOT must be an absolute path i think.

settings.py

```
# the url: myserver.com/static/
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
# refers to this directory: 
STATIC_ROOT = '/home/user/static server files'
```

let's say you put your css in "/home/user/static server files/css/" then refer to them like this:

base.html

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ STATIC_URL }}css/style.css" />
```

Comment: Try examining the html-source of your file after it's been rendered and see what the "href" points to. Maybe there's an indication of what's wrong.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you are working on a development server for now .

MEDIA_URL = 'http://localhost/media/'

calculated paths for django and the site
used as starting points for various other paths
`DJANGO_ROOT = os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(django.__file__))
SITE_ROOT = os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__))
PROJECT_ROOT = os.path.dirname(__file__)`

`TEMPLATE_DIRS = (
   os.path.join(SITE_ROOT, 'templates/'),
)`

`MEDIA_ROOT      = os.path.join(SITE_ROOT, 'templates/media/')`

The above should solve your problem as iot worked for me just fine.

While referring css files which are kept in "templates/media"
`<link href="/media/css/base/base.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"></link>`

Hope this helps you out

Answer (score 0):

hmm unfortunately this did not help. I could not find a variable STATIC_URL/ROOT in settings.py, so I added it as described above, also added the variable in base.html, but rendering still cannot find css file.

Another this I did is investigated code that works. I got a piece of good public application's source code and inspected base.html, and it says like this:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ cssRootUrl }}style.css"
```

then I went to check the settings.py and cssRootUrl was not defined there. So I have no idea where else could this kind of variable hide...

Answer (score 0):

this can solve your problem. I suggest you name your folder "static" for static files that you are using (css, js and images).

1. open your settings.py and

   -add this at the first line of your file:

   import os.path

   -change your STATIC_ROOT's value to:

   STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(PROJECT_DIR, 'static/')

   -change your STATIC_URL's value to:

   STATIC_URL = '/static/'
2. create a folder named "static" in your project root.
3. create a folder for your static files like css, javascript and etc. I recommend you use a different folder for different types of files.
4. open the urls.py of your project
   -add this to your imports: import settings
   -add this to the url patterns:

   (r'(?:.*?/)?(?P(css|jquery|jscripts|images)/.+)$', 'django.views.static.serve', {'document_root': settings.STATIC_ROOT }),

   NOTE: In this example, there are folders named css, jquery, jscripts and images inside my static folder.
5. In your template add this:

for css files: (in this example, default.css is the name of the css file)

```
<link href="/{{ STATIC_ROOT }}css/default.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all" />
```

for javascript:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/{{ STATIC_ROOT }}jquery/jquery.js"></script>
```